# Search engine cloaking

Tags: seo

I have implemented cloaking for search engines. In my category pages, it will display all the products if the user agent visiting is a search engine.

But how do I test it? Can I pretend to be a search engine? Do I wait till google indexes it and look at the cached result?

Comment: *starts the stop watch to time how long it takes for Google to black list*

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35769

"Make pages primarily for users, not for search engines. Don't deceive your users or present different content to search engines than you display to users, which is commonly referred to as 'cloaking.'"

Need we say more?

Comment: Oh please, nothing evil about showing more than 10 products in a category page. Since I do postbacks for paging, this way google can index what the actual intent of the page is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59) in Firefox, or spider the site yourself with [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) and specify the user agent with the -U option

It's worth noting that delivering different pages to some search engines (e.g. [Google](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66355)) can lead to the entire site being removed from their index.

Comment: I have creating another question for cloaking and black listing here...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029280/seo-blacklisting-for-cloaking

Answer (score 3):

There are addons for Firefox that let you set the User Agent.  Here's one:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59

I think the new Safari has this built in when you activate the Developer menu