# SEO blacklisting for cloaking

Tags: seo

I am using postbacks to perform paging on a large amount of data. Since I did not have a sitemap for google to read, there will be products that google will never know about due to the fact that google does not push any buttons.

I am doing cloaking to spit out all the products with no paging if the user-agent is that of a search engine. There may be some work arounds for situations like this which include hidden buttons to paged urls.

What about information you want indexed buy google but you want to charge for the content. Imagine that I have articles that I want users to be able to find in google, but when the user visits the page, only half the content is displayed and users will have to pay for the rest.

I have heard that google may blacklist you for cloaking. I am not being evil, just helpful. Does google recognize the intention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [FAQ](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66355) by google on that topic. I suggest to use CSS to hide some content. For example just give links to your products as an alternative to your buttons and use display:none; on them. The layout stays intact and the search engines will find your pages. However most search engines will not find out about cloaking and other techniques, but maybe competitors will denigrate you. In any way: Don't risk it. Use sitemaps, use RSS feeds, use XML documents or even PDF files with links to offer your whole range of products. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This is why Google supports a [sitemap protocol](http://www.sitemaps.org/).  The sitemap file needs to render as XML, but can certainly be a code-generated file, so you can produce on-demand from the database.  And then point to it from your robots.txt file, as well as telling Google about it explicitly from your Google Webmaster Console area.

Answer (score 1):

Highly doubtful.  If you are serving different content based on IP address or User-Agent from the same URL, it's cloaking, regardless of the intentions.  How would a spider parse two sets of content and figure out the "intent"?

There is intense disagreement over whether "good" cloakers are even helping the user anyway.

Why not just add a sitemap?

Comment: That is incredibly unhelpful!  I hate it when I visit a page for a search term and that term is not actually on the page I visitted, even when the site contains information on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think G will recognize your intent, unfortunately. Have you considered creating a sitemap dynamically? http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=40318

Comment: What about information you want indexed buy google but you want to charge for the content. Imagine that I have articles that I want users to be able to find in google, but when the user visits the page, only half the content is displayed and users will have to pay for the rest.

Comment: i believe it's possible to give google access to authenticated places... you have to give it a username and password, but i believe there may be a way that way.